# FOSUserBundle , dynamically change twig to render

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, overriding

In order to override a template for `FOSUserBundle`, I should create a twig file with the same name conserving the hierarchy. That's fine and it works perfectly.

My  problem is that the twig file is not static ( in the desktop version I will render a twig file  and in the mobile version we will render another one). I decide which twig to render on the controller by testing on a session variable.

Is there a solution to dynamically change the twig to render in `FOSUserBundle` without overriding all controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test your session variable in twig also. Simply include another template in your twig :

```
{% if app.session.isMobile %}
    {% include '::mobile.html.twig' %}
{% else %}
    {% include '::desktop.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Brilliant idea , I thought about it but not in this way. This way is much better.